# Отправка почты через внешний SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, smtp-server

Настроил локально на денвере как описано [здесь](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=email&page=007) 
все отлично работает, письма уходят, все супер. Перенес на хостинг пишет ошибку `fsockopen(): unable to connect to тут ip (Connection refused)`. Лома ломал голову, написал в тех поддержку хостинга, они мне ответили что у них запрещено юзать `fsockopen():`. Как же мне быть подскажите способ как отправить письмо бе этой функции?

Comment: вы не пробовали использовать более высокоуровневые решения? судя по датам в тексте статьи _(11 Aug 2007)_ ей уже почти 10 лет.

Comment: @teran не нашел ничего свежее, может вы что то посоветуете?

Comment: я если честно хз. Я пользую CakePHP, там [свои классы](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html) есть для работы с почтой. Тут часто встречались ссылки на [tag:phpmailer]. Также можно глянуть на [PEAR::Mail](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail). Думаю и другие популярные php-фреймворки имеют средства для работы с почтой.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте решение из моих сниппетов, у меня работало нормально

example.php

```
    <?php
//Замените настройки на нужные.
$mail_to = 'admin@your-domain.ru'; //вам потребуется указать здесь Ваш настоящий почтовый ящик, куда должно будет прийти письмо.
$type = 'plain'; //Можно поменять на html; plain означяет: будет присылаться чистый текст.
$charset = 'windows-1251';

include('smtp-func.php');
if ($_REQUEST['message'])
{
   $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
   $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
   $mail_from = $_REQUEST['mail_from'];
   $replyto = $_REQUEST['replyto'];
   $headers = "To: \"Administrator\" <$mail_to>\r\n".
              "From: \"$replyto\" <$mail_from>\r\n".
              "Reply-To: $replyto\r\n".
              "Content-Type: text/$type; charset=\"$charset\"\r\n";
   $sended = smtpmail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   echo '<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset='.$charset.'">
        </head>
              <body>';
   if (!$sended) echo 'Писмо не удалось отправить. Пожалуйста свяжитесь с администратором сайта по адресу: '.$mail_to;
   else echo 'Письмо было успешно отправлено. В ближайшее Вы получите ответ на него.';
   echo '</body>';
   exit;
}
Header('Location: mailer.html');
?>
```

smtp-func.php

```
<?php
$config['smtp_username'] = 'hostmaster@domain.ru';  //Смените на имя своего почтового ящика.
$config['smtp_port']     = '25'; // Порт работы. Не меняйте, если не уверены.
$config['smtp_host']     = 'mail.rucable.net';  //сервер для отправки почты(для наших клиентов менять не требуется)
$config['smtp_password'] = 'SECRET';  //Измените пароль (от почты)
$config['smtp_debug']    = false;  //Если Вы хотите видеть сообщения ошибок, укажите true вместо false
$config['smtp_charset']  = 'Windows-1251';   //кодировка сообщений. (или UTF-8, итд)
$config['smtp_from']     = 'Your Name'; //Ваше имя - или имя Вашего сайта. Будет показывать при прочтении в поле "От кого"

function smtpmail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers='') {
         global $config;
        $SEND =   "Date: ".date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " UT\r\n";
        $SEND .=   'Subject: =?'.$config['smtp_charset'].'?B?'.base64_encode($subject)."=?=\r\n";
        if ($headers) $SEND .= $headers."\r\n\r\n";
        else
        {
                $SEND .= "Reply-To: ".$config['smtp_username']."\r\n";
                $SEND .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $SEND .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"".$config['smtp_charset']."\"\r\n";
                $SEND .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
                $SEND .= "From: \"".$config['smtp_from']."\" <".$config['smtp_username'].">\r\n";
                $SEND .= "To: $mail_to <$mail_to>\r\n";
                $SEND .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n\r\n";
        }
        $SEND .=  $message."\r\n";
         if( !$socket = fsockopen($config['smtp_host'], $config['smtp_port'], $errno, $errstr, 30) ) {
            if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo $errno."&lt;br&gt;".$errstr;
            return false;
         }

            if (!server_parse($socket, "220", __LINE__)) return false;

            fputs($socket, "HELO " . $config['smtp_host'] . "\r\n");
            if (!server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Не могу отправить HELO!</p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
            if (!server_parse($socket, "334", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Не могу найти ответ на запрос авторизаци.</p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, base64_encode($config['smtp_username']) . "\r\n");
            if (!server_parse($socket, "334", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Логин авторизации не был принят сервером!</p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, base64_encode($config['smtp_password']) . "\r\n");
            if (!server_parse($socket, "235", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Пароль не был принят сервером как верный! Ошибка авторизации!</p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM: <".$config['smtp_username'].">\r\n");
            if (!server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Не могу отправить комманду MAIL FROM: </p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, "RCPT TO: <" . $mail_to . ">\r\n");

            if (!server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Не могу отправить комманду RCPT TO: </p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, "DATA\r\n");

            if (!server_parse($socket, "354", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Не могу отправить комманду DATA</p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, $SEND."\r\n.\r\n");

            if (!server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
               if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo '<p>Не смог отправить тело письма. Письмо не было отправленно!</p>';
               fclose($socket);
               return false;
            }
            fputs($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
            fclose($socket);
            return TRUE;
}
function server_parse($socket, $response, $line = __LINE__) {
        global $config;
    while (substr($server_response, 3, 1) != ' ') {
        if (!($server_response = fgets($socket, 256))) {
                   if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo "<p>Проблемы с отправкой почты!</p>$response<br>$line<br>";
                   return false;
                }
    }
    if (!(substr($server_response, 0, 3) == $response)) {
           if ($config['smtp_debug']) echo "<p>Проблемы с отправкой почты!</p>$response<br>$line<br>";
           return false;
        }
    return true;
}

?>
```

Comment: вас эта строчка не смущает?) `"To: \"Administrator\" <$mail_to>\r\n".
              "From: \"$replyto\" <$mail_from>\r\n".`

Comment: нет, а должно??

Comment: уже все ок, разобрался

Comment: это шаблон скрипта, его конечно же нужно править под себя

Comment: @LeshaZ, да все ок только у моего хостера отключена функция fsockopen, ваш скрипт ее тоже использует. Я поднял веб сервер на VPS и туда через CURL отпраляю тему письмо получателя а VPS уже отправляет дальше. Костыляра согласен, но пока выхода другого не нашел.

Comment: возможно хостер любезно согласится настроить под Ваши нужды что нить :)

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на PHPMailer - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

В папке examples есть примеры. Обратите внимание на расширение файлов - следует переименовать в php.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, универсальное современное решение - это Swift Mailer.
Надёжная, проверенная система отправки писем через свой (либо сторонний) SMTP. Простой в настройке, ставится через Сomposer. 
Подробный русский мануал [здесь](https://blog.lisogorsky.ru/send-mail-by-smtp).
Суть:

```
    // Create the Transport
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 25))
      ->setUsername('your username')
      ->setPassword('your password')
    ;

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    // Create a message
    $message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
      ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
      ->setTo(['receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'])
      ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
      ;

    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
```